# Local JSOn-File in Googlechart "Map"

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I have a small problem.

My plan is to display a GeoJSON (as a JSON locally stored) in a Google chart ('Map Chart').
Moreover my present JS code:

```
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['map'],"mapsApiKey": "AIzaSyD-
9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY" });

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

function drawMap() {
  var jsonData=$.ajax({
    url:'json',
    dataType:'json',
    async:false
  }).reponseText;

var data= new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
var options = {
  showTooltip: true,
  showInfoWindow: true,
   icons: {
        default: {
          normal: 'https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danieledesantis/playstation-flat/48/playstation-circle-icon.png',
          selected:'https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danieledesantis/playstation-flat/72/playstation-circle-icon.png'
        }
      }
};

var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

map.draw(data, options);
};
```

Who can help me or indicate another possibility?

Comment: `I have a small problem` - you seem to have forgotten to say what the problem is - `async:false` - don't do that

Answer (score 0):

the website show me, that the data format is not supported.

"The columns type does not match the supported data format. See documentation for supported formats."